# How do I calculate my Maneuver save DC if I use a Battle Master Maneuver while in Wild Shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, wild-shape, combat-maneuver, difficulty-class, battle-master

If I have a suitable Battle Master Maneuver (from three levels of Fighter, or through Superior Technique fighting style from one level of Fighter or the Fighting Initiate feat) and I use it when I make a "weapon attack" while in Wild Shape (from two levels of Druid), how do I calculate the Maneuver save DC?

> **Maneuver save DC** = 8 + your proficiency bonus + your Strength or Dexterity modifier (your choice)

Can I choose between my beast Strength or Dexterity each time, depending on what most suits my wild shape form? And which proficiency bonus do I use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### You use the beast's Strength or Dexterity, and your proficiency bonus

Wild Shape (p. 67 PHB) says:

> **Your game statistics are replaced by the statistics of the beast**, but you retain your alignment, personality, and Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores. You also retain all of your skill and saving throw proficiencies, in addition to gaining those of the creature. **If
> the creature has the same proficiency as you and the bonus in its stat block is higher than yours, use the creature’s bonus instead of yours**.

Since Dexterity snd Strength are statistics of the beast (and are not retained like the mental ability scores), you always use the beast's, not yours.

You only would use the beast's proficiency bonus if it had the same printed proficiency and its bonus was higher, which for example can happen for proficiencies like Stealth that some beasts like the [panther](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16976-panther) or [octopus](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16968-octopus) get an expertise-like proficiency bonus for. There is no beast with printed proficiency for Battle Master maneuvers, so you always use your proficiency bonus.